# kendo chart bar type series combined with line type series the chart reverts to a column type series

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

I'm trying to add a line type series i.e. "series.Line(s=>s.Name("goal")" to a chart -- this is being used to show a threshold of sorts.  The remaining series are bar types series: "series.Bar(s=s.Name("Rate1") and "series.Bar(s=s.Name("Rate2") and "series.Bar(s=s.Name("Rate3") and so forth.  If I remove the "goal" line code then the chart renders as horizontal bars as expected; however, if I include the "goal" line code then the chart renders as vertical columns (the default I assume). Any suggestions?

Comment: If the answers were useful please mark one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing understanding something here.

A line will travel from left to right showing (normally) the progression of a value (normally over a period of time).  meaning that their zero value with be on the horizontal axis.

The Bars have a zero value on the Vertical axis.

Therefore the 2 series types are incompatible.  Therefore, Kendo changes the chart from "Bar" to "Column".

So basically, what you're looking for is a Vertical Line series type (which I don't think exists).

You may want to look at showing these as Bullet charts instead.

http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/bullet-charts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/pareto-chart.aspx):

> The chart item does not provide built-in support for Pareto chart, in
>   other words the chart item would not be able to make the percent
>   calculations for you and you should take care of that prior to binding
>   the chart. When this is done you can achieve the same functionality by
>   combining Bar and Line series types. To create a second **Yaxis**
>   marked from 0% to 100% try the following code snippet:

```
chart1.PlotArea.YAxis.AutoScale = False
chart1.PlotArea.YAxis.AddRange(0, 100, 10)
chart1.PlotArea.YAxis.Appearance.ValueFormat = ChartValueFormat.Percent
```

Here's an example of how to calculate percentages in advance using MySQL:

```
SELECT a.`Year`, @count := (a.`count`) AS `Count`,
     @total := ROUND((@count)/(SELECT @total := count(`year`) AS `total` FROM `table` c) * 100, 2) as `% of Total`,
     @cumulative := (@total + @cumulative) as `Cumulative %`
FROM (SELECT @cumulative := 0, `year`,count(`year`) AS `count` FROM `table` `data` GROUP BY `year` ORDER BY `count` DESC) a
ORDER BY `Count` DESC;
```